# Matplotlip bar plot not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataset of bike trips for a month. I am trying to observe the peak hours of trips. So, I think the good way is to get the frequency of hours along the whole month and plot " hours vs. frequency " using bar plot as follows :

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(trip_data.starttime)
plt.figure()
plt.title('Days hours and number of users visitors/ frequency plot')
plt.xlabel('Day hours.')
plt.ylabel('Frequency of visits')
group_by_hour = trip_data.groupby([times.hour]).count()
group_by_hour.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

But the output is displayed in two different figures. One is blank one and another is with different labels. 
How to show the diagram in same figure? And how to remove those labels as well?

[image: bar plot of hours vs. frequency]

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.plot` accepts a keyword argument called `ax`, you probably have to pass an explicit `axes` to it. Such as `fig,ax = plt.subplots()` (instead of `figure`, for convenience), and then `group_by_hour.plot(ax=ax,...)`.

Comment: From experience, if you just extract the raw data and create the plot yourself, rather than using `group_by_hour.plot(kind='bar')`, you'll have a lot more control over what's being plotted and how. Or use the `ax` keyword argument, as suggested. That should do the trick.